# How do I use a method of a class that I got via Class.forName(String)?

Tags: java, methods, method-call

I need to use a method from a class that I obtained via the Class.forName() method. I'll give you an example:

```
public class Greeter {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Now I want to dynamically obtain this class using a string and use it's method like so:

```
Class c = Class.forName("Greeter");
System.out.println(c.getGreeting());
```

Now this obviously didn't work, because Java doesn't recognize the class as a Greeter class yet. How would I go about doing this without having to hard-code the fact that it's a Greeter class?

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this? In general, in order for you to know that you want to call a method on the class, you need to know what to expect anyway, and at that point you can simply directly use the class.

Comment: @chrylis, not necessarily. I have a map editor for a game and in the map editor I have a layer called "creatures" or "entities". In Java I can get all the objects from that layername and get their properties. The first property will be their classname. I will eventually have a ton of classes that I can fetch, but they all share the superclass "creature" which always has an update method. Using this, I can fetch all those classes, cast them to a Creature class and then call their update methods. Their update methods then do their individual thing. This way I don't need a ton of if-statements.

Comment: But you can do that without the hard reflection anyway: `if (c instanceof Creature)`.

Comment: @chrylis but then how will Java ever know that the creature object is a "pig" object for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, you would need an instance of the `Class` in order to invoke the method. For example,

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("Greeter");
try {
    Object o = cls.getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
    System.out.println(((Greeter) o).getGreeting());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You mention in the comments that you don't "know" it's a `Greeter`. You should program to a common interface, but failing that; it's possible to get the method by name as well. For example,

```
Object o = cls.getConstructor(null).newInstance(null);
Method m = cls.getMethod("getGreeting", null);
System.out.println(m.invoke(o, null));
```

Comment: But in your example you still need to hard-code Greeter in there eventually to be able to call it's methods. Is there no way around this? Doesn't it defeat the whole point? I have a list of a lot of different classes (Obtained by reading out a map editor for a game). But per map I usually only use a few of the classes. I don't want to write 50 if statements to check for all the classes...

Comment: Option 1: Program to a common interface. Option 2: Iterate the methods and decide which one to call; but option 1 is the better way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use methods of a class without knowing what the class is at compile time, you can use reflection:

```java
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("Greeter");
Object obj = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance(); // Use default constructor 
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName",<array of class objects representing argument types>);
Object result = method.invoke(obj,<array of arguments>);
```

However as noted in the first answer, it is better to use a common interface instead of reflection.

Edit: looks like the other answer beat me to the punch.

Comment: Also a great answer. For me Elliott's answer will work better, though. Because it just so turns out that all the classes I need to pull up dynamically share a parent class. But it's good to know that you can also do it this way.